# How to setup Webpack with ReactJS to open a specific page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Because i'am new to webpack i'am trying to adopt an existing app to it . So i manage to have some results , but i want to set up by default ( by launching of the app ) a specific page . ( the Home Page actually ) . Because i use routing without a top navigation and the first page that have to appear it has to be the home .

**webpack.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {

    entry: './src/index.js',
    module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: ['babel-loader']
          } , {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              { loader: "style-loader" },
              { loader: "css-loader" }
            ]
          } , {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
        ]
      },
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
      },
    output: {
      path: __dirname + '/dist',
      publicPath: '/',
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
      ],
    devServer: {
      contentBase: './dist',
      hot: true,
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "webpack-routing-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.8.4",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.25",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-moment": "^0.9.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2"
  }
}
```

**App.js**

```
  render(){
  return (
    <Switch>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div className='App'>
          <div className='mainContainer'>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Switch>
```

Maybe i'am doing something wrong , but please don't judge me hard . As i mentioned above i'am new at webpack so ... i will be gratefull if somebody gives me good answer . Thank you .

Comment: `the first page that have to appear it has to be the home` even if the user go to another page that isn't home? e.g. `/about`

Comment: Normaly yes but to trigger home page you have to click on the navigation . And i want to get rid of the top navigation , because this project doesn't need it

Comment: What do you mean by `top navigation` ?

Comment: ` <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>`

Comment: `i want to get rid of the top navigation` and you said that `top navigation` is `<ul> <li> <Link to="/">Home</Link> </li> <li> <Link to="/about">About</Link> </li> <li> <Link to="/topics">Topics</Link> </li> </ul>` so... just remove it? I can't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: at the moment if i remove it i cannot go to the home page . because home has to be triggered by the navigation .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192376/discussion-between-vencovsky-and-pandamastr).